# Mesh not changing programily

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to create my own version of Sebastian Lauge's marching cubes coding adventures (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3iI2l0ltbE) and I have a script that generates perlin noise into terrain on the Y-axis ant Im trying to make it so it creates perlin noise for the x, y, and z axis and compile vertices from that perlin noise into a mesh. Rightnow I'm in the process of adding the code to decides which points should be put into the mesh The problem is that I have to change the variable y in lines 49 - 56 to the variable ypn (declared on line 45) and leave the y variables out of that area alone the problem is that if i change one of those y variables (don't know which one) it will make the mesh flat and that's not what I want then it gets worse. If you try to revert the variable you changed back to y it will not change a thing. It will always make the mesh flat unless you make a new script. My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGen : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;
    Material material;

    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;
    Vector2[] uvs;
    Vector3[] interest;

    public int xSize = 20;
    public int zSize = 20;
    public int ySize = 20;
    [Range(-1, 1)]
    public float Surface = 0;
    public float Weight = 1;
    float minHeight = 0;
    float maxHeight = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();
    }
    void CreateShape()
    {
        vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];


        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(xSize, zSize, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        for (int y = 0; y <= ySize; y++)
        {
            for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
                {
                    float ypn = (Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * .3f, z * .3f) * 2f) * Weight;

                    vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, ypn, z);

                    if (y <= minHeight)
                        minHeight = y;
                    else
                    {
                        if (y >= maxHeight)
                            maxHeight = y;
                    }
                    var result = Mathf.Lerp(minHeight, maxHeight, Mathf.InverseLerp(0, 1, y));
                    texture.SetPixel(x, z, new Color(y, x, 1));

                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        texture.Apply();
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;

        triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }
            vert++;
        }
        uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];

        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
            {
                uvs[i] = new Vector2((float)x / xSize, (float)z / zSize);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.uv = uvs;


        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        MeshCollider meshc = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshCollider)) as MeshCollider;
        meshc.sharedMesh = mesh;

    }
}
```

Note: using unity 2019.2.15

Script is attached to empty Game object with a mesh renderer and a mesh filter on default unity values

Comment: Why do you tag both C# and UnityScript. You're either using one language or the other, surely?

Comment: @John agreed and it is definitely not UnityScript ^^

Comment: @Soupman So what is your question exactly?

Comment: What is `result`? It's never used. Also the part with clamping the `minHeight` and `maxHeight` has no effect as far as I can see.

Comment: I have no idea if it's a big in unity or is just me being dumb and how do I fix it